# Linq Double contains

Tags: c#, linq

In my DB I have this field :`mySerial Double?`
I have a Multicritera Search, and I have to search on this field.
User want to search on this field typing the start, the end or anything they want.

So I did this :

```cs
results.Where(x => x.mySerial.ToString().Contains(TextBox_mySerial.Text)) ;
```

When I search for : "88890"
I should have :888900, 888901, 888903, 888908, 888909 as result. 
But 
I only get : 888889

Linq turn `.ToString().Contains` my into:

```sql
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), [t0].[mySerial], 2) LIKE '%88890%'
```

But what I want is :

```sql
WHERE [mySerial] LIKE '%88890%'
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Linq or do I have to cast `[mySerial]` in my view into a varchar ?

Comment: I'm not surprised. I always thought there was special place in hell for ppl like me who do .ToString().Contains() on a int or a double.

Comment: If you run a query and select `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), [mySerial], 2)` what results do you get?  According to the docs the style for 2 will give scientific notation, so I wonder if that might be messing you up.  Just tried `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(888889 AS FLOAT), 2)` and the result was 8.888890000000000e+005.  So maybe try casting to `int` first?

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but what happens if you try `((string)x.mySerial).Contains(TextBox_mySerial.Text)`?

Comment: It is better to use BETWEEN than like.  Convert you textbox value to a double.  Working with strings you could end up with a rounding issue a miss some values because 8.88900 being a double may end up as 8.88899 as a text.

Comment: @juharr cant do `((string)x.mySerial).` Its notpossible to cast a nullable Double that way

Comment: @jdweng, there is no 'BETWEEN ' on a double field in the IntelliSense.

Comment: @PierreLebon did you try?  It wouldn't work in C#, but remember that it's being translated to SQL where `CAST(mySerial AS NVARCHAR)` would work.  There are many little gotchas like that when working with EF.

Comment: @juharr, you re right! The (int) work like a charm. Thx for your time. I Gave you the Green Tick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Linq is using a style of 2 for the conversion which results in scientific notation.  So the following query

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(888900  AS FLOAT), 2)
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(888901  AS FLOAT), 2)
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(888903  AS FLOAT), 2)
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(888909   AS FLOAT), 2)
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(888889 AS FLOAT), 2)
```

Gives these results

> 8.888890000000000e+005
>
> 8.889000000000000e+005
>
> 8.889010000000000e+005
>
> 8.889030000000000e+005
>
> 8.889090000000000e+005

So you either need to cast to `int` first

```
results.Where(x => ((int)x.mySerial).ToString().Contains(TextBox_mySerial.Text)) ;
```

Or enter something like "8.8890" instead.  Really neither one is a very good option so you might want to consider storing the value as a `NVarChar` instead if you need to do string operations on it instead of numerical ones.

Comment: Nice elaboration of the issue @ hand

Answer (score 0):

if you have a double you want to convert to a string then you HAVE to choose *some* string representation, as per this: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx you are going to get

> Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.

---

The solution is to provide your preferred format.  Is *seems* your field is actually an int? (ie all the examples you have given are whole numbers) so x.mySerial.ToString("0") should provide what you want.